# D3 zoom translateExtent calculation when target smaller than container

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming, translate-animation

For a work project I have a requirement to constrain a zoomable svg element within a container. I have a reduced example of the problem here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ryzp6x5lkn

In the above codesandbox I have a red `rect` contained within a `g` (`container`) within a square `svg` (`node`) canvas.

The `container` has a zoom '`zoom`' applied to it. On zoom event the `d3.event.transform` is applied to the `rect`.

The requirement is for the `rect` to be contained within the svg `node` at all zoom scales.

To do this I am applying a `zoom.translateExtent` and updating it on every transform.

```
const updateTranslateExtent = () => {

  const scale = container.property("__zoom").k;
  const containerBBox = container.node().getBBox();
  const containerTransform = container.node().getCTM();
  const containerTranslateX = containerTransform.e;
  const containerTranslateY = containerTransform.f;
  const viewportWidth = parseInt(node.attr("width"));
  const viewportHeight = parseInt(node.attr("height"));

  const extent = [
    [
      (viewportWidth - containerBBox.width - containerTranslateX) / scale * -1,
      (viewportHeight - containerBBox.height - containerTranslateY) / scale * -1
    ],
    [
      viewportWidth / scale + containerTranslateX * scale,
      viewportHeight / scale + containerTranslateY * scale
    ]
  ];

  zoom.translateExtent(extent);
};
```

This works to a certain extent but breaks down when a scale is applied.

Can anyone with any experience with d3 zoom help me here?

I've tried extensive googling and trial+error with the extent calculations but have not been able to get it working 100%.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out after much trial and error that this was the correct calculation:

```
const extent = [
  [
    (viewportWidth - containerBBox.width - containerTranslateX) / scale * -1,
    (viewportHeight - containerBBox.height - containerTranslateY) / scale * -1
  ],
  [
    viewportWidth / scale + containerTranslateX / scale,
    viewportHeight / scale + containerTranslateY / scale
  ]
];
```

Only slightly different but it was a lot of pain to arrive at this conclusion!

Here's an updated codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/7m5v9n0jmq

Comment: Thanks for documenting, this was super helpful!